# In Corda, how to get status of flow if my RPC client disconnects?

Tags: corda

I have written an RPC client that connects to my node and starts a flow. If my RPC client disconnects before the flow completes, how can I retrieve the flow and check its status (e.g. if it has completed)?

Answer (score 0):

The flow returns a unique identifier when started. If you store this unique identifier somewhere, you can use it later to retrieve the flow and check its status, e.g. by printing its current progress tracker step:

```
val flowId = cordaRPCOps.startFlowDynamic(MyFlow::class.java).id

val flow = cordaRPCOps.stateMachinesSnapshot().single { it.id == flowId }

val flowSteps = flow.progressTrackerStepAndUpdates!!

println(flowSteps.snapshot.last())
```

Comment: what if my flow was supposed to return a value to the rpc call? Instead of the Progress Tracker Update of the flow, I want to get the value which will be returned or already returned. is it possible ?

Comment: Not as of Corda 3, no.